# WPF Custom Control Usage and Access

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

Good afternoon everyone.  I realize that this subject may be covered in other places.

I am pretty experienced in C# but most of that experience was using console apps, Win Forms not WPF for GUI's, and not MVVM.  I am writing a program that detects USB-RS422 devices then provides the user configuration options for each device discovered.  The system will have 1->8 of these devices, initially it was 1->4 so I had manually created the layouts for each of them.  Now that the number has increased I have made an attempt at creating a custom UserControl but I am struggling with a few concepts.

Here is the code for my custom control:  rs422DeviceControlGroup.xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="EngineeringLabUi.rs422DeviceControlGroup"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:internal="clr-namespace:rs422DeviceControlGroup"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <GroupBox
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Header="Test"
        Style="{StaticResource GroupBoxStyle}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="rs422DevStackPnl" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Border BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="rs422DevEditCkBx" Content="Edit" />
                    <CheckBox x:Name="rs422DevUseCkBx" Content="Use" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Read Type" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="rs422DevReadTypeComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Write Type" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="rs422DevWriteTypeComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Border BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Baud" />
                            <ComboBox x:Name="rs422DevBoadRatesComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Parity" />
                            <ComboBox x:Name="rs422DevParityComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Data Bits" />
                            <ComboBox x:Name="rs422DevDataBitsComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Stop Bits" />
                            <!--  stop bits value of None is not currently supported  -->
                            <ComboBox x:Name="rs422DevStopBitsComboBox" SelectedIndex="1" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="FCC Position" />
                            <ComboBox x:Name="rs422DevFccPositionComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Status" />
                            <Ellipse x:Name="rs422DevStatusEllipse" />
                            <Button x:Name="rs422DevCheckBtn" Content="Check" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

And here is how it presents in design view [image]

1. When defining a custom control like this should I be setting names for the objects in the control such as this? `<Button x:Name="rs422DevCheckBtn" Content="Check" />`
2. When my application detects a device I want to add one of these controls to a TabItem but I am unsure how to get down into each of the checkboxes, comboboxes, ellipse and buttons.

I have also created styles in the App.xaml file as shown below:

```
<Application
x:Class="EngineeringLabUi.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources>
    <!--#region buttonStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion buttonStyle-->
    <!--#region borderStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="100" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion borderStyle-->
    <!--#region comboBoxStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <!--< debug />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />-->
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion comboBoxStyle-->
    <!--#region labelStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion labelStyle-->
    <!--#region textBlockStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,3,3" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
        <!--<Setter Property="bo" Value="Underline" />-->
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion textBlockStyle-->
    <!--#region groupBoxStyle-->
    <Style x:Key="GroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border
                            x:Name="Header"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="3,1,3,0">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion groupBoxStyle-->
    <!--#region checkBoxStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,1,1,1" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <!--< debug />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />-->
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion checkBoxStyle-->
    <!--#region ellipseStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion ellipseStyle-->
    <!--#region tabControltyle-->
    <Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion tabControltyle-->
    <!--#region tabItemStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3.5" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,-2,0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion tabItemStyle-->
    <!--#region menuItemStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <!--< debug />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF020202" />-->
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion menuItemStyle-->
    <!--#region flowDocumentStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="FlowDocument">
        <Setter Property="ColumnRuleBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="ColumnRuleWidth" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="IsColumnWidthFlexible" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="MaxPageWidth" Value="1000" />
        <Setter Property="PageWidth" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="MaxPageHeight" Value="700" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion flowDocumentStyle-->
    <!--#region gridStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="700" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1400" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion gridStyle-->
    <!--#region richTextBoxStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="500" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="700" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="500" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1000" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion richTextBoxStyle-->
</Application.Resources>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml I am able to use the control as shown below but like I said I am unsure how to set properties of the objects within the custom control.  Also, this is my first time making a custom control so I also wonder if I haven't done it correctly or if I should do something different.  My application is not currently MVVM but I do intend to migrate to that architecture in the near future.

```
    <!-- this is just a test control to organize the layout I intend to use elsewhere-->
<TabControl Margin="254,127,53,273">
    <TabItem Header="COM 4">
        <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <local:rs422DeviceControlGroup x:Name="SomeRs422Device" >
                <!-- I'm not sure what I should do here to access the parts of the control-->
            </local:rs422DeviceControlGroup>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="COM 5">
        <local:rs422DeviceControlGroup />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I suppose one approach would be to just have a TabControl with TabItems enough for 8 devices and then in the code behind do the instantiation there during runtime.

I'm looking for some advice on this as changes after this point in the application will require allot of rework and I would like to ensure that my approach is concrete before moving forward.  MVVM is somewhat new to me and so is WPF.  I appologise if this post is duplicating other post content.  I have been researching for about a week and need to move forward.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As to the other discussion, beyond what I've answered, whether you are taking a great or not great approach is something better suited for Stack's Code Review
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

In the future please try to keep questions very specific.  One question per post, this makes it easier to get the answers you need.  When you combine questions, you discourage those that may only know how to answer one of your questions from responding at all, and this doesn't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question number 1:

You need names when you want to reference the control in code behind(which is the last thing you want to do when you are implementing MVVM pattern) or when you are using bindings where simply you bind a value to your control in View from View Model property. If your contol is for example of type textbox and you have for example text property you will bind the value to your control in that View from the corresponding View model. Read about binding values to a certain control property which is exacly you want to do.

Question number 2:

If you want your solution in Model View View Model pattern fashion you need to learn about separation of concern in WPF.

Furthermore, simply as I said if you have a control(checkbox, combobox etc) you can bind a value to that control in that View from corresponding View Model. In short, you need to define everything in View Model related to your View(properties which you bind to controls values, commands for buttons if you have any etc and off course to implement INotify property changed inteface in order to have full real time working solution). So, you get it, you can make a View from your User Control and define everything for each control in View model and then you will have with every value you need and that is in short. I would like to mention that you need to check data templates which is a very powerfull thing when you want to define a something like this in WPF.

Finally, I would make a resource dictionary from everything you defined in App.xaml and reference it in the same file in merged dictionary and that is it.

So, in a case that you want a user control inside your WPF tab contols you would something like this:

```
<TabControl Name="myTabControl">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <local:YourUserControlName />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <local:YourUserControlName />
    </TabItem>
    <!-- Add more TabItems as needed -->
</TabControl>
```

where local is the namespace where you defined your user conrol.

In case that you want to use a View inside a tab control in WPF(because you want to define everything in View Model - properties for comboboxes, checkboxes etc.) you would do something like this:

```
<TabControl Name="myTabControl">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <local:YourViewName />
            </ContentControl.Content>
        </ContentControl>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <local:YourViewName />
            </ContentControl.Content>
        </ContentControl>
    </TabItem>
    <!-- Add more TabItems as needed -->
</TabControl>
```

Content Control will host your View. Finally, one of my favorite is to make a Data Template like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTabItemContentTemplate">
    <!-- Your UI elements and data bindings go here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Where this Data Temlate can be in a resource dictionary for example but you need to reference it in Main.

```
<TabControl Name="myTabControl">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTabItemContentTemplate}">
        <!-- Data context for Tab 1 content will be bound to the DataTemplate -->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTabItemContentTemplate}">
        <!-- Data context for Tab 2 content will be bound to the DataTemplate -->
    </TabItem>
    <!-- Add more TabItems as needed -->
</TabControl>
```

In this case, the content template property of each tab item is defined with Data Template(again with all your custom controls from a user control) and you need to set a data context in order to bind values and everything you need for those controls.

Finally, keywords are `View`, `View Model`, `Notify property change interface`, `Data Context`, `bindings` and that is it.

Comment: Ferid, Thank you so much for breaking that down for me.  Between your response and @Tarezed's response I believe I have a solid path forward.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelRiley I am sorry for some grammar mistakes and similar but I am glad you got it and in short - read about Model View View Model pattern and examine examples which will give you clues what to do and every contol(tab in your case) can be modified(in a proper way) in order to get a solution but you need practice and that is it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, Names are only needed if you need to reference them.  This can be referenced from things like a binding or code behind.

Your second question is loaded.  There are many ways to go about this and it's hard to give an answer without an opinion.  The most common, I think, would be a design pattern called MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel), where you loosely couple the controls to properties through binding.  There are MANY resources on MVVM, it's not really something I can do here.

You've said "Custom Control" several times, in fact this is a User Control.  There is a difference.  A custom control (sometimes called Templated Control in some XAML based UI) typically inherits from Control and provides for a control template.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I think you have just pointed out my fundamental misunderstanding between a Custom Control and a UserControl.  Would you say that implementing a Custom Control would be a better approach?

Comment: A user control in this case seems fine.  A user control is a collection of controls in a specific design, which seems to be what you have here.  A custom control is a "look-less" control.  It defines all the functionality and then can have one or more templates applied to it.  It referenced named "parts" in the template, but doesn't care how they are laid out or what other controls beyond the named parts might exist, it even has to assume the named parts might not exist.  Custom controls can be a lot more complicated to make.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend to start with MVVM.

1. You wouldn't need to use `X:Name`.
   You wouldn't need to create separate `UserControl` for each device.
   You'll have `Model` of your device. After device is added you just add it to the `collection`.
2. If you will use `ItemsControl` in your `View` it will display it.
   With `Command` you can pass parameter like an ID of your RS422 device.

Here's quick example of how to use `CommunityToolkit.MVVM`. You need to create folders in your project:

- Model with RS422Model class
- ViewModel with RS422ViewModel class

MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="RS422.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RS422" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:RS422.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:RS422.ValueConverters"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <d:Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:RS422ViewModel/>
    </d:Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:BooleanToColorConverter x:Key="BooleanToColor"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="20 0 0 0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Test" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Transparent">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RS422Collection}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <GroupBox Header="{Binding Id}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <CheckBox Content="Edit" IsChecked="{Binding IsEdit}"/>
                                                <CheckBox Content="Use" IsChecked="{Binding IsUse}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="Read Type" />
                                                <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ReadType}" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="Write Type" />
                                                <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding WriteType}" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Baud" />
                                                        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Baud}" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Parity" />
                                                        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Parity}"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Data Bits" />
                                                        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataBits}" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Stop Bits" />
                                                        <!--  stop bits value of None is not currently supported  -->
                                                        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="1" ItemsSource="{Binding StopBits}" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="FCC Position" />
                                                        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FCCPosition}" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="Status" />
                                                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColor }}" />
                                                        <Button Content="Check" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CheckCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </GroupBox>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    RS422ViewModel viewModel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new RS422ViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
     }
}
```

Your Model:

```
public partial class RS422Model: ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? _id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool? _isEdit;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool? _isUse;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[]? _readType;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[]? _writeType;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[]? _baud;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[]? _parity;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[]? _dataBits;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[]? _stopBits;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[]? _fCCPosition;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool? _status;
}
```

Your ViewModel:

```
    public partial class RS422ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<RS422Model> _rS422Collection;

        public RS422ViewModel()
        {
            RS422Collection = new ObservableCollection<RS422Model>();

            //TEST DATA where i = number of devices
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                RS422Collection.Add(new RS422Model()
                {
                    Id = i.ToString(),
                    IsEdit = true,
                    IsUse = true,
                    ReadType = new string[] { "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4" },
                    WriteType = new string[] { "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4" },
                    Baud = new string[] { "14400", "19200", "38400", "57600" },
                    Parity = new string[] { "none", "Even", "Odd" },
                    DataBits = new string[] { "none 1", "none 2", "none 3" },
                    StopBits = new string[] { "none 1", "none 2", "none 3" },
                    FCCPosition = new string[] { "none 1", "none 2", "none 3" },
                    Status = true
                });
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void Check(string parameter)
        {
            //TEST
            MessageBox.Show($"Test for device ID { parameter } ");
            if (parameter == "0")
            {
                //this is Device with Id 0
            }
            else if (parameter == "1")
            {
                //this is Device with Id 1
            }
            else if (parameter == "2")
            {
                //this is Device with Id 2
            }
              //and so on
        }
    }
```

`Check` button now will have `Command` with `parameter`.
You can create logic that manipulates elements in your `RS422Collection`. You can address to element as you'll do with arrays. For `Status` color you'll need to use `Converters` - like `bool to color converter` class. Just add folder to your project `ValueConverters` and create a class

```
public class BooleanToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
            }
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You'll need to add a namespace of `ValueConverters` folder in your `MainWindow`

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:RS422.ValueConverters"
```

Then you'll add `Converter` as a resource to your `MainWindow`

```
<Window.Resources>
     <conv:BooleanToColorConverter x:Key="BooleanToColor"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

When `Status` `bool` change - it'll switch `ellip's` `fill`.
Hope this helps.